# How to get SUM in Mysql from another table based on first table

Tags: mysql, get, sum

```
---------------colete--------------------
| id | id_comanda  | status | id_lista |
----------------------------------------
|    | 21775       | 0      | 3820     |
----------------------------------------
|    | 21776       | 0      | 3820     |
----------------------------------------
|    | 21777       | 0      | 3820     |
----------------------------------------


-----comenzi--------
| id  | taxComanda |
--------------------
|21775| 16.00      |
--------------------
|21776| 00.00      |
--------------------
|21777| 16.00      |
--------------------
```

I want to get SUM from column `taxaComand` from table `comenzi` by making the selection from column `id_lista` from table `colete`, so the SUM at the end to be `32.00`

This is what i have, but is not good.:

```
SELECT a.id_comnda AS a_id_comanda, a.id_lista AS a_id_lista,
b.id AS b_id, b.taxaComanda AS b_taxaComanda
(SELECT sum(taxaComanda) FROM comenzi WHERE b.id = a.id_comanda AS totalTaxaComanda)
FROM colete a
INNER JOIN comenzi b ON b.id = a.id_comanda
WHERE a.id_lista = 3820
GROUP BY a.id_comanda
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: taxaComanda: 16.00 + 00.00 + 16.00 = 32.00

Comment: Why? How does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I see no other answer than this :

```
SELECT SUM(b.taxComanda )
FROM colete a
INNER JOIN comenzi b ON b.id = a.id_comanda
WHERE a.id_lista = 3820
```

Comment: you are a god among mortals :D
This mini query works, now i need to apply it in my query is slightly more complex. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery and grouping id_lista:

```
SELECT id_lista, SUM(taxComanda ) as result,
FROM(
     SELECT id_comanda  , status , id_lista, taxComanda 
     from colete
     left join comenzi  on colete.id = comenzi.id_comanda)as sq
group by sq.id_lista
```

Comment: Thak you @tyro, i will try this to!
Great people here!